# I am unable to boot into Ubuntu 12.10. no matching password file entry in /etc/shadow add user

Tags: boot

I am unable to boot into Ubuntu 12.10. I have Windows 7 installed as well. The GRUB seems fine. I can boot into Windows. But when I boot into Ubuntu , the following appears.

"no matching password file entry in /etc/shadow add user 'varun'"

Answer (score 0):

This means your `/etc/shadow` file is missing user `varun`. [Information about the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` can be found here](http://tldp.org/LDP/lame/LAME/linux-admin-made-easy/shadow-file-formats.html).

Use a live CD or a GRUB rescue prompt. For the 2nd one follow the answer with images here [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Have a look at your `/etc/passwd` file with `more /etc/passwd|grep varun`  and at your `/etc/shadow` file with `sudo more /etc/shadow|grep varun`. if the 1st does contain a line and the 2nd does not you can re-create your shadow file with the command

[`sudo pwcon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pwconv.8.html)

After that you can use `passwd varun` to create a new password.

Comment: thank you for the information. Though I reckon my installation was faulty and a reinstall fixed it. However your help would come handy in the future. Thank you

Comment: drastic but I agree. In my newbie days I also a few times decided reinstalling would be better due to me doing the wrong thing ;)